# Thymeleaf interfering with JavaScript code

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating some JavaScript code where I use this instruction `var dps = [[]];`, but when I reload the template I get an error:

> Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "" (template: "dashboard" - line 7, col 16)`

This is the line that contain `var dps = [[]];` I tried to comment this line but keep getting the Thymeleaf parse error and when I remove it, I get a JavaScript error.

Here is my Spring Boot HTML template view:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var dps = [[]]; // this is the line that gives the error while parsing the template
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "light2", // "light1", "dark1", "dark2"
        exportEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Monthly Expenses"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: "true",
            legendText: "{label}",
            yValueFormatString: "#,###\"%\"",
            indexLabelFontSize: 16,
            indexLabel: "{label} - {y}",
            dataPoints: dps[0]
        }]
    });
    
    var yValue;
    var label;
     
    <c:forEach items="${dataPointsList}" var="dataPoints" varStatus="loop"> 
        <c:forEach items="${dataPoints}" var="dataPoint">
            yValue = parseFloat("${dataPoint.y}");
            label = "${dataPoint.label}";
            dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")].push({
                label : label,
                y : yValue,
            });     
        </c:forEach>    
    </c:forEach> 
     
    chart.render();
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you copy that part of your code that is making error?

Comment: sorry, i edited the question and now i think it is clear. also i removed the javascript tag since my question is related more to thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

- Try just declaring the "dps" variable like this

  ```
    var dps = [];
  ```
- Then, when you do

  ```
    dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")].push({
        label : label,
        y : yValue,  //this comma would make an error
    })
  ```

You should here declare the nested array like this:

```
//define nested array if not exists
if (!Array.isArray(dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")])) {
    dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")] = [];
}
//your code
dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")].push({
    label : label,
    y : yValue      //notice that comma isn´t here anymore 
})
```

This should work!